# Logback + Wildfly 8 - incorrect pattern

Tags: jboss, logback, wildfly

I have a problem with logback + wildfly 8 configuration. 
I'm using simple ConsoleAppender:

```
appender("STDOUT", ConsoleAppender) {
    encoder(PatternLayoutEncoder) {
        pattern = "%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{70} - %msg%n"
    }
}
logger("com.package.app", INFO)
root(DEBUG, ["STDOUT"])
```

The problem is that Wildfly appends to logback messages also server's log pattern.
It looks like:

```
11:31:49,954 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) 11:31:49.951 [default task-1] INFO  com.package.app.controller.FrontController - message...
```

As You can see, there is a server logs pattern first and then the logback message

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WildFly captures `System.out` and `System.err` and redirects them to a logger. You could configure a logger in WildFly with the name `stdout`, set the `use-parent-handlers` attribute to `false` and set the level to `NONE`. This should disable `System.out` from printing which means it will also not appear in the server.log.

That said, I don't see a reason to use logback for a `ConsoleAppender` since the server already provides one.