# Configure logback in Wildfly

Tags: jakarta-ee, logback, slf4j, wildfly-10

I have terrible problems to figure out how to configure logging via logback in my Java EE application on Wildfly 10. I tried to put `slf4j-api-1.7.21.jar`, `logback-classic-1.1.7.jar` and `logback-core-1.1.7.jar` in my ear in `/lib/`, add `logback.xml` to resources in my ejb module and add `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` into my ear `META-INF`. It almost works... Logback creates my log files and correctly log into them. Unfortunately logging to console works strange. It looks like wildfly concatenated default pattern with my pattern from logback configuration.

After that I tried to put logback as module into wildfly. I've added modules `org.slf4j` and `ch.qos.logback`. I've also made module `org.jboss.logging` depends of them. Configuration file (`logback.xml`) has been put into `$JBOSS_HOME/standalone/configuration` and `-Dlogback.configurationFile=$JBOSS_HOME/standalone/configuration/logback.xml` has been added to `JAVA_OPTS`. Unfortunately this work just the same.

I've tried to experiment with lots of combinations of two above approaches. I've tried different exclusions in `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` and different configurations of modules but none of them works. I pushed my sample project to github at https://github.com/mlewando/jboss-logback. I made two tags: `LOGBACK_IN_APP` for the first approach and `LOGBACK_IN_SERVER` for the second.

I'd really glad if someone has any idea what I'm doing wrong. I'm starting to have a little bit out of time with this. I've been doing googling and tries and errors for almost 4 days and it has to be working till Wednesday. I will very appreciate any help.

Update:
Just after posting this question, I found some other question about the same situation: [Logback + Wildfly 8 - incorrect pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22879141/logback-wildfly-8-incorrect-pattern) (as always, I find something right after posing my own question...). It gives some light on my problem, but didn't solve it. After following advice from answer that I found there, I end up with no logs in console at all.

Comment: See [Enable LogBack in JBoss by Leon on Anotheria](http://blog.anotheria.net/devops/enable-logback-in-jboss/)